# Equations of motion of displacement field

Tags: variational-principle, continuum-mechanics, vibrations, dispersion

We have an action: $$S[\boldsymbol{u}] = \frac{1}{2} \int dt \int d^3x \left\{  \mu (\frac{\partial u_{i}}{\partial t})^{2} - \nu (u_{ii})^{2} - \rho(u_{ij})^{2}\right\} $$

Where $u_{ij} = (\partial_{i}u_{j} + \partial_{j} u_{i} )/2$.

Where index $i = 1,2,3$ denotes the $x$ $y$ and $z$ axis and there is summation over repeated indices.

This models a three dimensional lattice of connected springs in the continuum limit. I want to derive the equations of motion of this system and the dispersion relation.

Using the EL equation I get:

$$\mu\partial_{tt}u_{1} - \nu \partial_{11}u_{1} - \rho \partial_{12}u_{1} - \rho \partial_{13}u_{1} - \rho \partial_{21}u_{2} - \rho \partial_{31}u_{3} = 0. $$

And similarly for $u_{2}$ and $u_{3}$. Is this correct and if so, how can I solve these equations to get the equations of motion? Also, how do I find the dispersion relation for this system?

Comment: Why are you not considering what you obtained from the Euler Lagrange equations to be the equations of motion?

Comment: Hmm you are I think right that these are the equations of motion. I guess what led me to believe that it wasn't the final answer is that I do not know how to obtain the dispersion relation from these equations.

Comment: @Nemo It is a standard elastic body admitting longitudinal and transverse waves. $\nu$ and $\rho$ are related to Lamé parameters and the Lagrangian density is of the form kinetic energy - elastic potential energy. To find dispersion relations you should pass in fourier integral representation decompising $\vec{u}$ on a basis for each momentum $\vec{k}$, made of $\vec{k}/|\vec{k}|$ itself and two orthogonal vectors $\vec{e}_1(\vec{k})$ and  $\vec{e}_2(\vec{k})$. You will see that way that modes decouples and you find two speeds of propagation, longitudinal and  transverse.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer :

Define functions $u_i(p) = u_i(p^0,p^1,p^2,p^3)$ as Fourier transform of the functions $u_i(x)$

Then take the Fourier transform of your three Euler-Lagrange equations. 
You get three equations of kind :

$A_{11}(p)u_1(p) + A_{12}(p) u_2(p) + A_{13}(p)u_3(p) = 0$

(The functions $A_{ij}(p)$ are quadratic functions of the $p^i$)

The system of 3 equations has a non trivial solution $u_i(p)$ if and only the determinant det $A$ is  zero.

det $A = 0$ gives you the relation of dispersion, because it is a relation between the $p^i$.

From these 3 equations, maybe you are able to find an manageable expression for the $u_i(p)$, maybe trying expression like $u_i(p) = B_{ijk}p^j p^k \Phi(p)$, and introducing this expression in the 3 equations (which in fact are now linearly dependent, so you can only choose 2 of the 3 equations) may lead you to be able to extract the $B_{ijk}$  from quartic equations in the $p^i$ (but this is only a guess).

Comment: dispersion relation is obtained by taking fourier transform with respect to time and not space.

Comment: @guru : Dispersion relations are constraints on momentum/energy,  so you need Fourier transform on time and space.